# Determine if all the characters in a string are unique using bit-manipulation

Tags: python, string

> Implement an algorithm to determine if all the characters in a string are unique.

Can someone explain me how to do it using bit manipulation? There is a solution provided using bits in CTCI but I am unable to understand it.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the solution or show what you do already understand about the solution?

Comment: What is CTCI? What is the solution you don't understand?

Comment: Probably that means Cracking The Coding Interview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets implement an algorithm to check if string contains duplicate characters using Bit Manipulation in python.
Return True for "abcdgt" and False for "bdb"

## Bit manipulation algorithm to check duplicates only take O(n) time

and O(1) space as we would be using only 4 bytes of space to check if
a string contains duplicate characters or not.
For this problem we only assume that string contains character from a-z only as an integer can only store 32 bits maximum.

```
    # 1<<val shifts 1 by to the left by appending zeros equal to val. So 1<<5 would be 100000. So this means that if a char is present in string, we assign 1 at its place else 0. If checker already has 1 at the place of char and we take '&' with val(value of character in range 0-26) again, we will get 1 (1 & 1), which is greater than zero. Hence it shows that char is present or string contains duplicate characters. 
    Lets take an example for str = 'bdb'. 
      checker = 0
    1. c = 'b' 
         => val = 98 - 97 = 1 
         => 0 & 1<<1 
         => 0 & 10 
         => 0
         checker = 0 | 10
         checker = 10
    2. c = 'd'
         => val = 100 - 97 = 3
         => 10 & 1<<3
         => 10 & 1000
         => 0
         checker = 10 | 1000
         checker = 1010
   3. c = 'b'
         => val = 98 - 97 = 1 
         => 1010 & 1<<1 
         => 1010 & 10 
         => 1 > 0; return False (which is true as string contains duplicates)
```

Below is the code for the algorithm.

```
def checkDuplicates(str):
    checker = 0  
    for c in str:  
    #Gets the difference in ASCII between character and 'a'
    val = ord(c) - ord('a')
    if (checker & 1<<val) > 0:
        return False
    checker |= 1<<val
```

return True

Hope, i was able to explain bit manipulation as lot of my friends even don't understand this concept and find this hard but it's actually easy.

Answer (score 1):

From what people are saying online, it seems to work like this:

Assuming you have a string (containing only the characters from either the set a-z, or from the set A-Z, but not both), you keep track of which characters have been seen before by using bitwise operations to flip bits in an integer. For example, if your string is "aza", you'd set the first bit in your integer to a 1, then you'd set the twenty-sixth bit to a 1, and then you'd attempt to set the first bit to a 1 again. Since it's already been flipped, you can assert that this character has been seen before, and is therefore not unique. The restriction on the character set (a-z or A-Z) seems to arise from the fact that there are 26 letters in the alphabet, and 32 bits in an integer in most languages, so you have enough bits to represent the entire alphabet.

However, I don't think this is a great solution to the problem using Python, since integers have arbitrary precision in Python. It's also not a great solution in general, in my opinion. You're better off using a `set()` to keep track of previously seen characters, and then asserting that the length of the string matches the length of your set.